# Última posição de um Array

Tags: php, array

Em PHP, qual é a maneira mais rápida e simples de obter a última posição de uma Array?

Eu consegui isso fazendo `$array[ count($array) - 1 ]`, e funciona, mas existe alguma maneira mais simples e menos feia?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pode usar o [**end()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

```
$ultimo = end($minhaArray);
```

Outra alternativa é o `array_pop()` mas esse método remove também o último elemento, não sei se é o que precisa.

---

Se fôr uma array associativa precisa de colocar a array no ultimo item e depois ir buscar a `key()`

```
end($minhaArray);         
$ultimaChave= key($minhaArray);
```

---

Se quiser criar uma nova array com o ultimo elemento, pode usar o [**array_slice()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), este método permite criar uma nova array com vários elementos da array original, atravéz do segundo parametro que indica quantos elementos do fim devem ser passados.

```
$ultimo = array_slice($minhaArray, -1)
```

Comment: Quem votou negativo pode também deixar explicação se encontrou alguma incorreção.

Comment: Valeu! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava!

Answer (score 6):

Para deixar o array no ultimo elemento utlize a função [end()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php)

```
$arr = array ('maça', 'banana', 'melancia', 'morango', 'uva');
echo end($arr);
```

a saida é : `uva`

Comment: Porquê o voto negativo? `+1`

Answer (score 5):

A função [end()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php), faz o ponteiro apontar para o último elemento do array, logo se você fizer:

```
$array = array('primeiro','segundo','último');

var_dump(current($array));
var_dump(end($array));
var_dump(current($array));
```

a saída será:

```
string 'primeiro' (length=8)
string 'último' (length=6)
string 'último' (length=6)
```

A função [current()](http://docs.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.current.php), retorna a posição atual do array